# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '0' in Stack trace: #0. PHP Insert based off API response

Tags: php, mysql, api, exception, error-handling

im using RottenTomatoes Api to gain film information. I have a list of 250 films im grabbing information on however i get to a certain point and i get this error. It seems to happen randomly. I'm taking the api results and putting them in my own database. Would there be a reason for such an error?

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '0' in /home/ignitet1/public_html/CheckFilm/RottenTomatoes.php:340
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ignitet1/public_html/CheckFilm/RottenTomatoes.php(156): RottenTomatoes-&gt;getResource('http://api.rott...')
#1 ****/loadFullData.php(37): RottenTomatoes-&gt;getMovieInfo('771269025')
#2 {main}
  thrown in ****RottenTomatoes.php</b> on line <b>340</b><br />
```

on line 340 this is the code. rottentomatoes.php is a php library used to parse the response's from the api.

```
if (isset($decodedResponse['error']))
            throw new Exception('API Error: ' + $decodedResponse['error']);

        return $decodedResponse;
```

Apologies for the poor explanation i'm having trouble finding the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Is `RottenTomatoes.php` a script you wrote or supplied by someone else?  What is around line 340? It seems like `getResource` is throwing an exception with little information about what went wrong but looking in there may reveal where the exception is originating from and why.

Comment: Here is the code on 340, the script is a public php library for use with the api

Comment: So it looks like the error "0" is sent by the remote API but I searched all over their site and docs and found no pages talking about errors at all.  Someone on the forum mentioned error 596 so 0 must be some strange error code, I just have no idea what it means or where to find documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious bug in the code is that this line:

```
throw new Exception('API Error: ' + $decodedResponse['error']);
```

should be:

```
throw new Exception('API Error: ' . $decodedResponse['error']);
```

Instead of the `+`, there should be a `.` for concatenating strings. After that correction, you should see the exception text correctly. However the real problem is why the exception is thrown in the first place, which is probably (due to the `if (isset($decodedResponse['error']))`) an error retrieved from the server, or the decoding/parsing fails for some reason.

However, there is no answer to why is this happening, because the problem is inside the library, not in the code you posted.